# Is it possible to disable eureka client level cache?

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I want to disable eureka client level cache. I found this [link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/reference/html/appendix.html) doesn't contain configuration for client level cache. Are there anyway to disable eureka client level cache?

Comment: Are you using eureka alone or with ribbon or spring cloud load balancer?

Comment: Hi @spencergibb i am using spring cloud gateway as eureka client.